# How to make std::function reference

Tags: c++

How do I make a reference to the callable object? I would like to create a pub/sub with std::function. From the below code, have I made a copy of `Test`, or it was something else? Alternative suggestion also welcome.

```
using Callback = std::function<void ()>;

struct Test
{
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << a ;
    };

    int a;
};

struct Sub
{
void Subscribe(Callback callback)
{
    callback_ = callback;
}

void trigger()
{
     callback_();
}

Callback callback_;
};

int main() {

    Test a = {1};

    Sub sub;
    sub.Subscribe(a);
    a.a = 2;
    sub.trigger();

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your program? What output do you get? If the output is `1` then you know that a copy was made. If the output is `2` then you know a reference was kept.

Comment: So alternatively how do it make a reference? possible using bind to fix this?

Comment: Note that there are actually *two* copies being made here.  Firstly the argument to `Subscribe` is being constructed with a copy of the `Test` object.  Secondly, `Sub.callback_` is set with a copy of that argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) as follows:

```
sub.Subscribe(std::ref(a));
```

or make a lambda function with a reference capture:

```
sub.Subscribe([&a](){ a(); });
```

Now that you're passing a reference instead, make sure `&a` is not dangling after it exits the local scope. (There can be many *good* ways to prevent that)

Comment: does the Subscribe method look good, if I used the std::ref ?

Comment: @BryanFok It depends on the definition of what *looking good* is, but I don't see any problem in this particular example that you provided. `std::ref` is from the standard library and generally accepted and used. So as long as you understand what that is, it shouldn't harm you.

Comment: Could you take a look another similar question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211746/whats-the-different-between-make-pair-and-pair