# What's the different between make_pair and pair?

Tags: c++

If you run the below code, you will print 3412, which mean `std::make_pair` ignored the `std::ref` here. I want to do understand what is happening here?

```
using Callback = std::function<void ()>;

struct Test
{
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << a ;
    };

    int a;
};


struct Sub
{
void Subscribe(Callback callback)
{
    callback_ = callback;
}

void trigger()
{
     callback_();
}

Callback callback_;
};



int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<Callback, int>> test_vtor;  
    std::unordered_map<int, Test > test_map;


    test_map[1].a = 1;
    test_map[2].a = 2;
    test_vtor.push_back(std::pair<Callback, int>(std::ref(test_map[1]), 1));
    test_vtor.push_back(std::pair<Callback, int>(std::ref(test_map[2]), 2));

    test_vtor.push_back(std::make_pair(std::ref(test_map[1]), 1));
    test_vtor.push_back(std::make_pair(std::ref(test_map[2]), 2));

    test_map[1].a = 3;
    test_map[2].a = 4;

    std::for_each(test_vtor.begin(), 
                    test_vtor.end(), 
                    [&](auto& pair){
                        pair.first(); 
                });
}
```

Comment: Yes, [`make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) is supposed to unwrap reference_wrappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So on [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50211045/921070), `std::ref` does not work with `test_vtor` as follows:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Callback, int>> test_vtor;
```

Even if you pass a reference:

```
test_vtor.push_back(std::make_pair(std::ref(test_map[1]), 1));
```

you **cannot** avoid your `Callback` being copied.
That's the same reason that declaring `std::pair<Callback&, int>` is not allowed.

Even if [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) has this exceptional rule for `std::reference_wrapper` as follows:

> ... unless application of std::decay results in **`std::reference_wrapper<X>` for some type `X`, in which case the deduced type is `X&`**.

There will be always a new copy of `Callback` in `test_vtor` (whether it's moved or copied), which will surpass its reference-ness during the construction.

Comment: Well, not exactly. `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is turned into `T&`, which does preserve reference-ness. It's effectively the same as `test_vtor.push_back(std::pair<Test&, int>(test_map[1], 1));`, which also doesn't work. The reference-ness gets lost slightly later.

Comment: @hvd, You are right. `std::ref` does preserve reference-ness. What I meant is the reference-ness gets lost later on  by `std::make_pair`.

Comment: IMO reference-ness gets lost in `std::decay` which is deduced as `std::remove_cv<std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type`

Comment: But that's my point: it doesn't. The reference-ness doesn't get lost by `std::make_pair`. The resulting `std::pair<Test &, int>` holds `test_map[1]` as a reference. It's the construction of `Callback` (aka `std::function<void()>`) where the reference gets lost.

Comment: @hvd *It's the construction of Callback* - True, because the return type is no longer a reference by `std::decay`. Am I correct about what you're saying?

Comment: @DeanSeo `std::decay<std::reference_wrapper<T>>::type` is just `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. `std::make_pair` then has a special exception to turn that into `T&`. `Callback` then takes that by value (without involving `std::decay`).

Comment: @hvd, You're right. My bad. It deduces to `T&` exactly. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for the note btw.

Comment: @GauravSehgal There's no `std::remove_cv` involvement for `std::make_pair`. There's a special helper template class specialization for `reference_wrapper<_Ty>` where it gives an alias `using type = _Ty&` in `std::make_pair`